# SSH run command in users rbenv enviroment

Tags: ssh, openssh, ruby

Anyone know how to make `ssh` source the users enviroment?

```
 ssh -Y -t old-dash '"bundle exec rails server"
bash: bundle exec rails server: command not found
Connection to old-dash closed.
one@localhost ~/github/ui $
```

I have the below in my `.bashrc` and I do not think it is getting sourced:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See if this helps you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919321)

```
ssh <host> bash --login -c <command>
```

Start bash as a login shell through SSH and then load the **rbenv** via SSH's `-c` option.

Comment: That didn't work, but you set me in the right direction....thanks! `If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a
     login shell.`